# suddenly can't shift up?

Tags: road-bike, shifter, mechanical

First things first, I am not very good at mechanics, so if my question looks very inexperienced, sorry for that.

I bought a road bike with shimano ultegra r8000 and after 2 years during a descend I wanted to shift up the front derailleur but I just heard a click and it didn't work. since then I feel a big resistance when I press the lever. The shifting to the smaller ring seems fine (I can press the lever), but the other way around not.
I wanted to investigate it a bit before I go to a mechanics, so I looked inside and this is what I saw:
[image]

I marked on the picture that little black rectangle which seems to stop the lever agains shifting up (doesn't move at all)

Then I checked the cable too with a screwdriver if I could pull it a bit and it seems like it would not be an issue:
[image]

This is why I thought it might not be an issue with the cable.
My question would be, is it some problem that is easy to investigate from here and I can fix myself, or it is better to bring my bike to a service?

Many Thanks,
Mate

Comment: Does the derailleur move easily if you pull on the exposed inner wire with your hand?  Should be easily accessed at the frame's downtube or toptube.    If not, can you move the deraileur by shoving it directly with your hands?   The shifter may not be at fault.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see if the cable is fraying at or near the end that's in the shifter? If so, the cable will have more play in it, so it shifter will hit the stopper before the derailleur can shift the chain (or sometimes even move the derailleur at all).

If it is frayed, immediately change out that cable before it breaks. Often, a broken cable is impossible to remove from the shifter and you'll wind up having to replace the entire shifter. Be thankful you got a warning sign.

If the cable looks fine, check the derailleur clamp to ensure that it is tight and that the cable does not have too much slack in it. If it is, then try following a derailleur adjustment like this one by Park tools:

If that doesn't work, then it's time to visit your LBS.